# Vuetify v-select items-text property does not work in v3. (Fill value in v-select Vue3)

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, items, v-select, vuetifyjs3

I use Vuetify v3 and try to fill a v-select by using items and `items-text` property but it doesn't work.
The v-select display 2 empty slot.

```
<v-select ref="structure" :items="structures"  item-text="name" item-value="uuid" label="Structure" v-model="listStructure" return-object ></v-select>
```

The data is correctly filled in with an Get request in the create method of the page.

But the list seems two have two data but empty.

Below the example of one data

```
{
  "name": "strcuture1",
  "uuid": "1b0d3f5f-8806-47a5-be63-cef12865c07b"
}
```

Comment: gettind a shot view into vue select docu, it seems you should set `name` as label attribute instead of `Structure`

Comment: Is it the `Vuetify` Select?

Comment: @wendt88 No Label is only the title of the list.

Comment: @Tolbxela Yes I think this is the vuetify select. Thanks for your answer below. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v.3 you should use `item-title="name"` instead of  `item-text="name"`.

They have changed from [`item-text`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#props-item-text) in v2.6 to [`item-title`](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/upgrade-guide/#v-select-v-combobox-v-autocomplete) in v3.

Check the ['v-select/v-combobox/v-autocomplete'](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/upgrade-guide/#v-select-v-combobox-v-autocomplete) section of the Vuetify's [Upgrade Guide](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/upgrade-guide/#upgrade-guide).

Here is the playground:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify;

const App = {
  data() {
      return {
          listStructure: null,
          structures: [
            {
              "name": "structure1",
              "uuid": "1b0d3f5f-8806-47a5-be63-cef12865c07b"
            },
            {
              "name": "structure2",
              "uuid": "1b0d3f5f-8806-47a5-be63-cef12865c07b"
            }            
          ]
      }
  }
}

const vuetify = createVuetify();
const app = createApp(App);
app.use(vuetify);
app.mount('#app');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.2/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.2/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-select ref="structure" :items="structures"  item-title="name" item-value="uuid" label="Structure" v-model="listStructure" return-object ></v-select>
  Selected:<br/>
  <span v-if="listStructure != null">
    Name: {{listStructure.name}}<br/>
    uuid: {{listStructure.uuid}}
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: In fact it was the update of vuetify which was needed !! We use before the 3.0.0-beta and by using the 3.1.2 it works. Thanks @Tolbexla

Comment: Indeed, they have changed from [`item-text`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#props-item-text) in v2.6 to [`item-title`](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/upgrade-guide/#v-select-v-combobox-v-autocomplete) in v3